# Fancybox2 not opening full width on first load

Tags: image, load, width, fancybox

I am using fancybox2 on my website at www.baseshamai.com.
If you click portfolio and then (only the first 2 thumbs work right now) click a thumbnail for the first time, it either loads a skinny piece or loads it from a weird place. However the next time you open the same thumbnail it will load it correctly.
Why is this happening?
And even when I set minWidth to auto it opened the right size but in a weird place.

I should mention that these pages that are being loaded via fancybox have almost no content, rather they have divs that have background images. I thought it was smarter to break up the images.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are opening external pages, better use `fancybox.iframe` instead of `fancybox.ajax`. If you use the second, fancybox will try to get the dimensions from the incoming content and resize itself after a re-calculation of the dimensions. The next time you open fancybox, it opens correctly since the dimensions have been already cached.

Also, if you want to have better control over the size of the box, you may try adding the `width` and `height` API options to your custom fancybox script.

Comment: Why? what is the difference between using ajax and iframe? Wont it still try to get the dimensions?

Comment: fancybox will try to get dimensions from the incoming content when 'autoSize' is set to 'true' and 'type' is either 'inline', 'ajax' and 'html'. You use iframe type when the page you want to load has its own html structure, styles, etc. and can render as regular http page out of fancybox ... in that case, fancybox cannot get dimension form an iframe type document and you should set them as options.

Comment: Ajax on the other hand, is normally used when you want to pull chunks of information from a html, txt, php or asp document. Such documents may or may not have a proper html structure and unless you set dimensions inside of such documents, you should set autoSize to false and width and height as fancybox API options to avoid those "unexpected" results (check the fancyapps.com - autoSize documentation)